# ORACLE APEX - Losing radio group value in region on cancel and submit in Tabular Form

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle-apex, regions

I have a region at the top of my form with a radio group. I have a tabular form in a region at the bottom of the form.  When I hit submit or cancel on the tabular form I lose the selected radio value in the top region.  Is there a simple solution to this problem?  I am new to radio groups.

John

Comment: What do you mean "lose the value"? Is the value NULL when examined by a page process, or is the item reset when the page is loaded afterwards?

Comment: The the item reset when the page is loaded afterwards.  How can I capture the item save it and reload after the submit, cancel, etc...

Comment: Check the **Source Used** attribute on the item. If it's set to *"Always, replacing any existing value in session state"*, you probably want to just change it to *"Only when current value in session state is null"*.